# Code crash when storing objects in `std::map`

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

```
 typedef std::map<int, MyObject*> MyMap;
 MyMap* myMap = new MyMap;
 // ...
 myMap->insert( MyMap::value_type( 0, objectOfType_MyObject ) );
```

Why does my code crash with a stack trace going down to

```
 std::less<int>::operator()
```

?

I understand that if I use a custom key class that I must provide a comparator, but this is an int.

I've never used maps before and it's probably a dumb question but I've been stuck on this for ages now.

Thanks

Comment: What is all the stack trace look like?

Comment: provide a complete stack trace or use valgrind to detect some memory misuse :-)

Comment: May be a dumb comment..but are you sure you are not deleting myMap object before insert?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This code works (compiles & runs) for me:

```
#include <map>

class MyObject
{ };

int main(void)
{
    typedef std::map<int, MyObject*> MyMap;

    MyMap *myMap = new MyMap;
    MyObject *obj = new MyObject;

    myMap->insert(MyMap::value_type(0, obj));

    delete obj;
    delete myMap;
}
```

So the problem lies in the details (`// ...` or what `MyObject` can do) or elsewhere. You can probably fix things up a bit to help. Try to stack allocate things when you can. Do you actually need a pointer to a map? I suggest you don't:

```
#include <map>

class MyObject
{ };

int main(void)
{
    typedef std::map<int, MyObject*> MyMap;

    MyMap myMap;
    MyObject *obj = new MyObject;

    myMap.insert(MyMap::value_type(0, obj));

    delete obj;
}
```

And do you actually need to store pointers to object, or objects?

```
#include <map>

class MyObject
{ };

int main(void)
{
    typedef std::map<int, MyObject> MyMap;

    MyMap myMap;

    myMap.insert(MyMap::value_type(0, MyObject()));
}
```

Much smaller, and almost impossible to get memory leaks. If you *do* need to store pointers, for polymorphic behavior, check out [boost::ptr_container library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/headers.html), which has a [map adapter that stores pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_map_adapter.html).

Comment: Very good answer; In the last case, he might also need to define a copy constructor for MyObject.

Comment: My problem was that I am not .clear() 'ing the map on initialising my class. (Even though it is size 0). I am storing Obj-C objects